# <div element with results> disappears instantly

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

As usual, this ran well in the useful codepen but now in vs studio/ chrome it's maybe reloading immediately, so the final calculation does not remain on the page long enough to see it.  I do have the class hidden but it's removed in the js.  ...  preventDefault? but I'm not sure where to prevent it.  now I'm just typing because it won't post my question without more words. this is great

```js
function calculate (){
    let vehiclePrice = document.getElementById('price').value;
    let downPayment = document.getElementById('downpmt').value;
    let tradeIn = document.getElementById('trade-in').value;
    let intRate = document.getElementById('interest-rate').value;
    let loanTerm = document.getElementById('loan-term').value;
    
    amount = +vehiclePrice;
    down = +downPayment;
    trade = +tradeIn;
    r = +intRate;
    term = +loanTerm;
    amountFinanced = amount - down - trade;
    
    console.log(amount)
    
     annInterest = parseFloat(r),
        monInt = annInterest / 1200;
  
        if(!amount){
          alert('Please add a loan amount');
          return;
        }
      
       if(!term){
         term = 60;
         loanTerm =    document.getElementById('loan-term').value = 60;
       }
      
      if(!down){
        down=0;
        downPayment = document.getElementById('downpmt').value = 0;
      }
    
    
      if(!trade){
          trade = 0;
          tradeIn = document.getElementById('trade-in').value = '0';
        }
    
      if(!annInterest){
        r = 3.25;
        intRate = document.getElementById('interest-rate').value = 3.25;
      }
    
    let calculator = ((monInt + (monInt / (Math.pow((1 + monInt), term) -1))) * (amountFinanced || 0)).toFixed(2);
    
    let paymentResults = document.getElementById('results');
    paymentResults.classList.remove('hidden')
    paymentResults.innerHTML = '';
    
    let results = document.createElement('div');
    results.innerHTML = `<h1> Estimated Montly Payment:</h1> <h3> ${calculator} `
    
    paymentResults.appendChild(results);
  }
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
  
  #calculator{
      padding: 89px;
  }
  
  label{
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #666; 
  }
  
  #form{
    display: block;
    align-items:left;
    justify-items: left;
    margin-right: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 18px; 
  }
  ::placeholder {
    color:red;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  input[type=text] {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    width: 30em;
    padding: 9px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  
  #btn{
    color: white;
    background: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 30px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px black;
  }
  
  #btn:hover{
    padding: 9px;
    background: #6732;
    color: #232323;
  }
  
  #results{
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px #232323;
    position: relative;
    left: 600px;
    width: 80%;
    bottom: 500px;
  }
  
  .hidden{
    display: none;
  }
  
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1{
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    input[type=text]{
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 15em;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    #calculator {
      width: 20%;
      padding: 40px;
      
    }
    
    #results{
      position: relative;
      left: 10px;
      top: 20px;
      background-color: red;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: left;
      align-self: left;
      margin-left: 0 auto;
      min-width: 300px !important; 
    }
  }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href=style.css>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<div id='calculator'>
    <div='form-calculator'>
    <form id='form' action=''>
      <h1> Car Loan Calculator</h1>
      <label for='price'>Vehicle Price</label>
      <input type='text' id="price" placeholder='vehicle price'>            </input><br>
     <label for='downpmt'>Down Payment</label>
      <input type='text' id="downpmt" placeholder='down payment'> 
    </input><br>
  <label for='trade-in'>Trade in Value</label>
      <input type='text' id="trade-in" placeholder='trade-in'> 
    </input><br>
  <label for='interest-rate'>Interest Rate</label>
      <input type='text' id="interest-rate" placeholder='interest' value='3.25'>
    </input><br>
  <label for='loan-term'>Loan Term</label>
      <input type='text' id="loan-term" placeholder='ex. 60 months'> 
    </input><br>
  <button id=btn onclick='calculate();' value=calculate>Calculate</button>
  </form>
    <div>
      <div class='hidden' id='results'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i called event.preventDefault(); after the variables were declared and that worked perfectly.

Comment: You could also just set the button type to button,  `<button type="button" ..../>`  The default type for a button is submit.

Comment: @RyanHartley try pressing "enter" in one of the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

The code presented always calculates estimates on the front end. Hence the simple solution to prevent form submission is to replace

```
<form id='form' action=''>
  ...
</form>
```

with

```
<div id='form'>
  ...
</div>
```

If you need to retain the `form` element for whatever reason, then you could add a submit handler to prevent form submission such as

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener( "submit", function( event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```